# What is use of @EnableEurekaClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created 2 Spring boot apps, One is Eureka server and second is normal spring boot app without any code and in second app I have just added maven dependency as follows

```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

I haven't used any annotation like @EnableEurekaClient in second app, and have not configured any eureka related properties in application.properties.

Still my second app is getting registered with Eureka. How? If it happening just due to maven dependency then what is use of `@EnableEurekaClient`?

Comment: One is Eureka server that would keep all the services registered with itself and other is client, where it would register itself with eureka server.

Comment: The annotation is an abbreviation of a list of actions you need to do to be registered. If you are getting registered, you probably wrote code to do so. It is best to understand how :) and whether you code performs all the actions the annotation covers.

Answer (score 9):

The `@EnableEurekaClient` annotation is not required anymore. Simply adding `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` to dependencies will enable the client. If you want to disable it, set the property value of `eureka.client.enabled` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have used the `SpringCloundApplication` annotation in your bootstrap class in your client app.  Like below:

```
@SpringCloudApplication
public class Application {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
      }
}
```

@SpringBootApplication, giving us the same autoconfiguration, component scanning, and property
support (among other things) that we have come to love. Additionally, it adds @EnableDiscoveryClient
to register with Eureka and @EnableCircuitBreaker so we can create fallback commands if a remote service is down. Below is what the SpringCloudAnnotation contains:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public @interface SpringCloudApplication {
}
```

There are both @EnableEurekaClient and @EnableDiscoveryClient annotations available.
DiscoveryClient is the abstract interface that Spring Cloud Netflix puts above EurekaClient in
the event that future service registry tools are built. At this point in time, there is little
difference in our code, except the convenient usage of a single
annotation,@SpringCloudApplication, to turn our component into a microservice.

**Conclusion:**
EurekaClient is for service discovery with Eureka.
DiscoveryClient is a interface, a standard for other implementation of service discovery tools.

Example with Eureka Client

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
    }

}
```